# Rails Paperclip copy set of images from model A to model B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

Currently I have a model A (ItemRequest) that has many images.
Once this item request has been approved, it creates a model B (Item) that also has many images.

I'm using paperclip to handle image upload to S3, and what I would like is that after the approve process has been completed, copy the images from model A to model B, duplicating them.

Following some similar questions (but none using models with many images) I've written the following in my ItemRequest model approve method.

```
if images.length > 0
  item.images = images.map { |img| img.dup }
end
```

And this apparently creates a new set of Image models, but when trying to access the url, it does not open any image and S3 returns 403.
I've checked and no image is created in S3. I can access other images so the S3 is properly configured.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
def resolve! user_id
  if status != RESOLVED
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.resolved_by_id = user_id
      self.resolved_date  = DateTime.now
      self.status         = RESOLVED
      save!

      catalog_item = Item.create(
          name:            item_name,
          oem_name:        oem_name,
          description:     description,
          category_id:     category_id,
          make:            make,
          part_number:     part_number,
          uom:             uom,
          cost_in_cents:   cost_in_cents,
          weight_in_grams: weight_in_grams
      )
      if images.length > 0
       catalog_item.images = images.map { |img| img.dup }
       catalog_item.save
      end
    end
   end
   true
end
```

Something is worth mentioning that doesn't simplify things, is that my Image model is polymorphic.

I've managed to write a solution but not happy with it yet.

Add this to the Image model

```
def file_remote_url=(url_value)
  self.file = URI.parse url_value
  @file_remote_url = url_value
end
```

And then

```
catalog_item.images = images.map { |img|
  new_image = Image.new()
  new_image.file_remote_url = img.url
  new_image
}
catalog_item.save
```

Also, this solution does not work locally if uploading to the dev machine.

Comment: Maybe it is just missing the `save` of the item or images. Can you show the whole action?

Comment: Updated and tried calling explicitly save. Still the same problem, the image model gets created and added to the database, but the image url takes to a unexisting path

Comment: `catalog_item.images << images.map { |img| img.dup }`  try this

Comment: Still same problem. URL's changed but images were not really copied anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of trying different approaches, here is what solved the issue for me:

```
catalog_item.images = images.map do |img|
  new_image = Image.new
  new_image.imageable_type = 'CatalogItem'
  new_image.imageable_id = catalog_item.id
  new_image.file = img.file
  new_image
end
```

This will create a copy of the image instead of changing the reference only. As far as I understood, if you're using S3 and paperclip, it won't simply copy the image using the S3 api but rather make a copy and upload it again, which might be a bit inefficient, but that is a whole other unrelated issue.